# store hosts IP addresses in variable file instead of inventory

Tags: ansible, ansible-vault

I tried to look this up online but can't find a clear answer. Is it possible to store inventory hosts' IP addresses in the playbook or in var files like group_vars or host_vars or even myvault.yml? something like:

```
[webserver]    
webserver_ip_variable
```

then that variable would be defined in some var files like group_vars/all/myvars.yml as:

```
webserver_ip_variable: 8.8.8.8
```

is that any possible? The goal is to store the IP addresses in a vault.yml file, what would be the best way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Q: *"The goal is to store the IP addresses in a vault.yml file, what would be the best way to accomplish this?"*

A: Ansible doesn't have to know the IP address of the remote host as long as either the *alias* or *ansible_host* is resolvable. See [Connecting to hosts: behavioral inventory parameters](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/intro_inventory.html#connecting-to-hosts-behavioral-inventory-parameters). For example, let's create an inventory file

```yaml
shell> cat hosts
[srv]
srv1 ansible_host=srv1.example.com
srv2 ansible_host=srv2.example.com
srv3 ansible_host=srv3.example.com
```

Then create the vault file with the IP addresses. For example

```yaml
shell> cat group_vars/srv/ip.yml
srv_ip:
  srv1: 192.168.1.11
  srv2: 192.168.1.12
  srv3: 192.168.1.13
```

[Encrypt the file](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/vault.html#encrypting-unencrypted-files)

```sh
shell> ansible-vault encrypt group_vars/srv/ip.yml
Encryption successful
```

Now it's possible to use the encrypted file in the playbook. For example

```yaml
shell> cat pb.yml 
- hosts: srv
  tasks:
    - debug:
        var: srv_ip[inventory_hostname]
```

gives

```
shell> ansible-playbook -i hosts pb.yml 

ok: [srv2] => {
    "srv_ip[inventory_hostname]": "192.168.1.12"
}
ok: [srv1] => {
    "srv_ip[inventory_hostname]": "192.168.1.11"
}
ok: [srv3] => {
    "srv_ip[inventory_hostname]": "192.168.1.13"
}
```

Comment: That won't work unless, for example, `srv1.example.com` is resolvable, in which case you don't need the IP addresses at all.

Comment: Yes. This is the content of the first sentence. You got it right. You'll be better off to comment on the question to learn what the IPs are for if you really need it. [Delete the comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19756/how-do-comments-work).

Answer (score 0):

As you say, you can vault a file with the IP addresses.  So your inventory can have two files, one with the hosts, and one with the IPs:

`inventory/hosts`:

```
srv1
srv2
srv3
```

`inventory/ips` (vault this file):

```
srv1 ansible_host=192.168.1.11
srv2 ansible_host=192.168.1.12
srv3 ansible_host=192.168.1.13
```

Of course, you don't really need that `hosts` file, but you can use that to group hosts, too.